# Adding Variables in HLA?

Tags: assembly, hla

So, I'm trying to add variables, but it doesn't want to work. I have a really simple program.

```
program tested;

var
    i: int8;
    x: int8;


begin tested;
    mov(10, i);
    mov(5, x);
    add(i, x);
    stdout.put(x);

end tested;
```

I get the following error:
"Error in file 'tested.hla' at line 11 [errid:129712/hlaparse.c]:
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('. Near: << ) >>"

Mov is supposed to move the number into the variable..and add is supposed to add two things. Why isn't it working?

I don't really understand hla so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about HLA, but generally you cannot add memory to memory. Try to change `add(i,x);` to `mov(x, al); add(i, al); mov(al, x);`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Once I used the registers, it worked.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. By the way, you should accept answers for your previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that 5 and 10 are  "constants" and you cannot change the values of 5 or 10.
Remember `mov(dest, source);` 
for example:
`mov(x,i);` copy the value of i and put it in the address of x

Comment: HLA is `op(src, dst)`.  http://plantation-productions.com/Webster/HighLevelAsm/HLADoc/HLARef/TOC_html/HLAReferenceTOC.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
add( source, destination );
```

In case you weren't privy, both destination and source operands cannot be memory locations. That's why it's not working.

Source can be register, constant, or memory
Destination can be register or memory
Both cannot be memory
Both must be the same size